# PHP loop while not empty array

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner to php/sql so bear with me if I'm missing something.

I have a database that I'm querying but not all the rows are complete. I'm trying to figure out which rows have a value in a certain column.  Essentially what I have now is:

```
while (!empty($result['c1'])) 
{
echo $result['c2'];
}
```

The server doesn't seem to like this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Putting your condition in the while loop will going to stop the loop at the first occurrence of a `$result['c1']` value.

Comment: If that value is empty this loop will go on forever and if that value is not empty then it will stop on first pass. Unless you add some code inside the loop to change the of c1 this is never a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have a while loop, this goes in it like so...
Ignore the mysql part....Im just illustrating...you should use PDO anyways...but since you're still learning, Im assuming you're just using mysql_* deprecated functions, as thats where most of us start.

```
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

     if(!empty($result['c1'])){
       echo $result['c2'];
      }

   }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  For what it's worth, I'm using mysqli_ functions.  I don't know if that's any better or not.

Comment: You can do prepared statements with mysqli so its far better....PDO is just database agnostic, its just another layer of abstraction, thats all.